# Rails double render

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know this isn't valid code, but is there a way to do something like this in Rails?:

```
render "$('#dialog').replaceWith(#{render :action => 'new.html.erb'});"
```

What I'm trying to do basically is replace the contents of a JS dialog with what is/would be returned from calling `render 'new.html.erb'`.

Edit for @Devin M:

controller action:

```
def new
  @act = Act.new(:user_id => current_user.id)
end

def create
  @act = Act.new(params[:act])
  if @act.valid?
    @act.save
  else
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

new.js.erb:

```
$('#dialog').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render(:action => 'new.html.erb')) %>");
```

Full error:

```
Showing app/views/acts/new.js.erb where line #1 raised: undefined method `formats' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split this code out into a seperate view since including it in the controller would go against the ideas of MVC. I would update the controller to respond to JS requests using some code like this in the action I wanted to modify:

```
  respond_to do |format|  
    format.html { redirect_to @item }  
    format.js  
  end
```

And create a view like this with the extenstion `.js.erb`:

```
$('#dialog').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "new.html.erb", :locals => { :act => @act }) %>");
```

You can then trigger this JS with a remote link to the action or by adding your own UJS.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but the following error is raised pertaining to the code in the view (new.js.erb): `undefined method 'formats' for nil:NilClass`. Any clues on that?

Comment: Can you post your controller and view please? As well as the full error.

Comment: Done. Added to original question.

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that. Added.

Comment: Try the new JS code and see if that works or changes the error.

Comment: I tried with and without the respond_to call. It didn't make a difference either way.